# on click event of checkbox called when clicked 2nd time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I wrote this code

```
   $(document).on("click", "#tasksTable tr", function(e) {
       var taskId = this.id;
       var chkBoxCompleted = $(this).find('input:checkbox:first');
       var chkBoxNotRequired = $(this).find('input:checkbox:last');

       chkBoxCompleted.on('click', function(){
           alert("called when I click second time on checkbox")
       });

       chkBoxNotRequired .on('click', function(){
           alert("called when I click second time on checkbox")
       });
    });
```

and my html is like

```
<table width="100%"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;" id="tasksTable">
   <tr id="9">
   <td class="blueFont_inset"><span>22/05/2014 00:48</span>&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="blueFont_inset"><input type="checkbox" name="completedTask[]"  id="completedTask" value="N"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
   <td class="blueFont_inset"><span>Completed Date</span>&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="blueFont_inset"><input type="checkbox" name="notRequiredTask[]" id="notRequiredTask" value="N"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

These are multiple rows inside this table.

Click event of checkbox called when I click any of the checkbox second time. I tried it in IE and Chrome.
Is this because I am using it inside table row click event? But I want to use that table row click event too.

I am using

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Event handlers inside event handlers will do that, and it's not even the right event handlers, you should be using the change event, and not nest them.

Comment: Um, every time you click on the row, you will be adding clicks, that is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first click event is being intercepted by the click listener on the TR. Rather than using a click binding to bind events to the inner elements, I would bind it all on document.ready and make all references relative to the clicked elements parent scope.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it how I can write them separately.. thanks

Comment: Change the ID's to classes (ie: completedTask), and bind the events directly to them. If you need the row ID, inside of your click event callbacks, find $(this).parents('tr').attr('id') to get it.

Comment: It looks like he is already using delegate syntax on the parent row binding

Comment: you mean I should write it like '$(document).on("click", "#tasksTable tr .completedTask", function(e) ' if I change id to classes. it still not working

Comment: I don't need rows. Rows are already there. I just displayed one row to save space.

Comment: Take the row click wrapper off. It's a good rule of thumb not to do delegate selection off the document, rather $('#tasksTable').on('click', 'input.completedTask', function(e){});

Comment: Just for shit and gigs, let me explain .on() delegation syntax for a second. $ used to use .live() and .delegate(). This traversed the entire dom to find new elements to attach events to. That shit sucked. So the new on syntax lets you specify where your traversal occurs within. This speeds things up considerably. So the format is basically $(parent of possible elements).on('event', 'target element', callback(){});

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove check box click handlers before bind again otherwise click event is binding again and again while click event is propagated to tr.

**Ref:**
*http://api.jquery.com/off/*

Better avoid binding event handlers with in parent event handler.